# C# - How to Determine a Form's Title bar font?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, titlebar

I want to create a form that is wide enough to show the title bar string, which is dynamic.  To compute the string's text width, I need to know the title bar font.  How do I query it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SystemFonts.CaptionFont`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemfonts.captionfont(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> Gets a Font that is used to display text in the title bars of windows.

Sample usage:

```
using System.Drawing;

var font = SystemFonts.CaptionFont;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to be the powershell equivalent:

```
function Get-CaptionFont {
    $font_family = ([Windows.SystemFonts]::"CaptionFontFamily").Source
    $font_size = [Windows.SystemFonts]::"CaptionFontSize"
    return New-Object System.Drawing.Font($font_family, $font_size, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]"Regular")
}
```